# Multiple Android expandable lists in a layout

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to have more than one expandable list within a layout.  It appears that an expandable list in a custom layout must have an id of "@id/android:list".  So, how could I have more than one if they would need to have the same id?  Thanks...

Answer (score 7):

They don't have to have the `@id/android:list` ID - they only have to have that ID if you are using a `ListActivity` or `ExpandableListActivity`. Just use a normal `Activity` and give them unique IDs.